# Clustering To Find Most Likely Time Period From Count Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

So I have a histogram for counts of events by hour for a number of IDs. I need to be able to define an approach to be able to cluster the counts to find which hours the counts are most likely to occur. And from there, be able to identify the IDs that are most likely to occur. Can anybody please help point me in the right direction. I apologize as I am still relatively new to clustering. Thanks

[image: Histogram]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your plot, I think you can try gaussian mixture

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

Y = np.random.poisson(lam=(10., 20.), size=(200, 2))
Y.resize(400,1)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=Y)
df.columns = ['Time']
sns.distplot(df)
```

[image]

You can get the Time in one of the clusters:

```
df.loc[df['labels']==0].Time
```

Using something like that, we plot:

```
sns.distplot( df.loc[df['labels']==0].Time , color="skyblue", label="0")
sns.distplot( df.loc[df['labels']==1].Time , color="red", label="1")
plt.legend()
```

From the model, you can know the most probable time (or max) time,

```
gmm.means_.flatten()
#array([24.18011343, 10.2643123 ])
```

Which is not far away from what we simulated. You can then predict the probability of using these means and a poisson distribution.

[image]